# write list by index to file

Tags: python, file

Hello everyone I need your help So I read a file and save the information in from this file in list, and then I try to print this information to another file but only the information in the parity indexes and the problem is to access to this indexes. I would be happy if you can you help to fix it

```
file_read = open("/Users/Po/Desktop/test.txt","r")
file_write = open("/Users/Po/Desktop/test1.txt","w")
data = file_read.read().splitlines()
file_read.close()

for i in xrange(0,len(data)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        #print data[i]
        file_write.write(data[i])

#print len(data)
#for i in xrange(0,len(data))
file_write.close()
```

Comment: so, what's not working?

Comment: write to file doesn't print the write text

Comment: Can you post an example of what the file contains, and what you'd want the output to be. My guess is that you are looking for the 2nd, 4th, 6th... lines, but getting 1st, 3rd, 5th... lines. If that's the case, then your if statement should be `i % 2 == 1`

Answer (score 1):

First, it is best to handle files using the `with` statement (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html). That way, you won't have to close the files after you are done. Second, you don't need to load the entire file in memory. Just do it line by line:

```
with open("/Users/Po/Desktop/test.txt","r") as file_read, open("/Users/Po/Desktop/test1.txt","w") as file_write:
    for i, data in enumerate(file_read):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print data
            file_write.write(data)
```

This should write the 1st, 3rd, 5th, ... lines. If you want the 2nd, 4th, ... use `i % 2 = 1`.

If you do not see data printed, it probably means that there is nothing in `file_read`

Answer (score 0):

if its reading from one file and writing to another file....

```
with open("/Users/Po/Desktop/test.txt","r") as file_read:
    data = file_read.read()
with open("/Users/Po/Desktop/test1.txt","w") as file_write:
    file_write.write(data)
```